# doctrine 2 loggable gedmo with XML

Tags: php, xml, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to make DoctrineExtensions work for my Doctrine 2 in combination with XML.

It looks like I'm close, but everytime I try to load an entity my website dies with a fatal error:

```
Class must be annoted with Loggable annotation in order to track versioned fields 
in class
```

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping">
    <entity name="Base\Activity\Organisation" table="activity_organisation">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
        </id>
        <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="255" precision="0" scale="0">
            <gedmo:versioned/>
        </field>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>`
```

Now the question: How do I annotate my class with Loggable annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot one part of the xml. I've had to add the following:

`<gedmo:loggable log-entry-class="Log\Location"/>`

Where log-entry-class is the class you want to use for logging. Complete xml now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping">
    <entity name="Base\Activity\Organisation" table="activity_organisation">
        <gedmo:loggable log-entry-class="Log\Location"/>
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
        </id>
        <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="255" precision="0" scale="0">
            <gedmo:versioned/>
        </field>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```